# Unexpected parameter: start_time (tweepy)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use a search query for retrieving tweets for some given search words but I am getting the following error:

```
Unexpected parameter: start_time
```

The query works fine without the `start_time` parameter.

I am using the following code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=words, lang="en", start_time='2021-03-01T00:00:00Z', tweet_mode='extended').items(25)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've not seen an example of using a cursor with `start_time`. I think it's usually using the id of a tweet with `start_id`. Do you have confirmation that `start_time` works with a cursor?

Comment: I am not sure but the documentation says so: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all

Comment: Oh, what is made available by Twitter may not necessarily be implemented by Tweepy.

Comment: I only see `start_time` made available using `Client`: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/bd4e3d58b3eb0de5ae1303a3bfbe3a70ed9f9180/tweepy/client.py And the documentation for that: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?highlight=client#tweepy-client-twitter-api-v2-reference

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where this is documented, but this may work for you. And it may be dependent on your tweepy version.

```
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Cursor
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json
import datetime


auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


start = datetime.datetime(2021,9,14)
end = datetime.datetime(2021,9,14,23)

search_term = "#italy"

tweets = [tweet for tweet in Cursor(api.search, q=search_term, lang="en", since=start, tweet_mode='extended').items(10)]

for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet._json.get('text'))
    print(tweet._json.get('entities'))
```

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't work on `tweepy version 4.4.0` and `Twitter API v1.1`. BTW, I am using `search_tweets` API for retreiving tweets, documentation here:`https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=search_tweets#tweepy.API.search_tweets`. It gives the error: `Unexpected parameter: since, Unexpected parameter: end`